# Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated magento 2 php 7.1.25 vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 81

Tags: magento2

Getting this error while moved files to another location on same server

`Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated.`

This message will be suppressed on further calls in:

> /vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 81

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This error because of version compatibility. please check which prerequisites for the particular version of Magento

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/fatal-error/m-p/110880#M4953

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.2 is not compatible with php7.2 You must use php7.0